# How can I set a Global Variable from within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set a Global Variable from within a function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var option = '';

    $("[name=select_option_selected]").change(function() { 
        var option = $(this).val();
        alert(option); // Example: Foo  
    });

    alert(option); // Need it to alert Foo from the above change function    
});
```

Comment: Avoid global variables - consider using jQuery's data() method as I mention in my answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Declare it outside the scope of your jQuery onready

```
var option = '';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[name=select_option_selected]").change(function() { 
        option = $(this).val();
        alert(option); // Example: Foo  
    });

    alert(option); //This will never be "Foo" since option isn't set until that select list changes
});
```

if you want to initialize this to the current selected value try this:

```
var option = "";
var $select_option_selected = null;

$(function() {        
    $select_option_selected = $("[name='select_option_selected']")
    $select_option_selected.change(function() { 
        option = $(this).val();
    });    
    option = $select_option_selected.val();
});
```

Comment: Technically, if you don't declare it, the browser will declare it globally, but this is unsafe and will not pass strict mode in the future (coming soon to a browser near you =D)

Comment: Thanks, it was the extra var inside the change() that was making it local to the function

Answer (score 6):

**The Bad Way**

As the other answers point out, it's **not a good idea** to create global variables.  And as they point out, you can create a global variable by:

- Declaring variable outside of all functions
- Initializing your variable without the `var` keyword
- Or, declaring it as a property of the window object: `window.options = 'blah';`

**Using jQuery's `Data()` Method**

But there is a better way of creating a globally accessible value using jQuery (and other libraries). In jQuery, use the `data()` method to store values associated with DOM elements:

```
// store 'blah' at document root
$(document).data('mysite.option', 'blah');

// retrieve value
alert($(document).data('mysite.option'));
```

Notice `"mysite"`... it is a good idea to namespace your data keys for the same reason it is good to namespace global variables in javascript.

Comment: I disagree that setting global data on the document is any better than creating a global variable. Still has all the problems of globals, plus it requires a lot more typing

Comment: I see what you're saying, but the data method is not doing what you think. See this answer for an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905994/i-know-its-bad-to-store-data-in-the-dom-but-why

Comment: My comment has nothing to do with the implementation of `$.data`, you don't know how I think `$.data` is implemented. The problem is that something that is associated with the whole document, suffers from the same problems as creating a global variable, everybody accessing and changing it, name collisions. The broader you scope your stuff, the more likely you are to run into problems

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var option = '';

    $("[name=select_option_selected]").change(function() { 
        option = $(this).val(); //no declaration of new variable, JavaScript goes to what encloses the function
        alert(option); // Example: Foo  
    });

    alert(option); // Need it to alert Foo from the above change function    
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you want to? global variables are generally to be avoided. In the browser, `window` is the global object, so if you do `window.option = ...`, then `option` will be available globally.

I highly recommend naming a global variable something more unique than "option", to avoid clobbering existing stuff.

Another option, which I also don't recommend: leave off `var`

```
myvariable = 'foo';
```

If myvariable has never been delcared before, it will be declared as a property on window, making it global. This is generally considered to be (very) bad practice however.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `window.` prefix to access a global variable from within the scope of a function

```
window.option = ...;
```

Comment: I don't ever use globals, but if forced to do so, I also use `window.varName` or `self.varName` for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Two approaches not mentioned by anybody else, applicable when you: 1. don't have access to the *global* LexicalEnvironment,<sup><sup>[10.2.3](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.3)</sup></sup> and 2. are trying to write code that you wish to support systems wherein a direct reference to the global object<sup><sup>[15.1](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1)</sup></sup> (such as `window` in the HTML DOM, or `GLOBAL` in Node<sup>[1]</sup>) isn't guaranteed:

1. Make an **indirect**<sup><sup>[15.1.2.1.1](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.1.1)</sup></sup> call to `eval`, by wrapping it in a superfluous PrimaryExpression, thus: `(1,eval)(...)` (the digit and comma operator are meaningless) … and then calling the result thereof. This forces the code to be run in the global execution context.<sup><sup>[10.4.2](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.2)</sup></sup>

   We can then declare<sup><sup>[10.5](http://es5.github.io/#x10.5)</sup></sup> a new variable in the global lexical environment, as suggested above; or, for that matter, do anything else that we desire within that environment:

   ```
   function global_define(ident, value){
      (1,eval) ("var "+ident+"; (function(v){ "+ident+" = v })") (value) }
   ```
2. To be less round-about (and, to boot, avoid the [FUD](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fud&defid=181688)-ridden `eval` call), we can directly access the global object and set a **property**<sup><sup>[4.2](http://es5.github.io/#x4.2)</sup></sup> on it, which will then be available as a global variable elsewhere in our code.<sup>[2]</sup>

   Instead of taking the `eval` approach above and gaining access to the global object via code we've written in the global context, it turns out we can access the global object as the `this` value<sup><sup>[10.4.3](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3)</sup></sup> within any function that is called with `null`:

   ```
   var global = (function(){ return this }).call(null)
   global[ident] = value
   ```

**Phew.**

Okay, more reading, for those of you who haven't fainted from specification links and `eval` calls, yet:

1. [@kangax](http://twitter.com/) covers all of the bases [quite thoroughly](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/). Seriously, read that if you have any questions I haven't answered here (including those relating to the all-important idiosyncrasies browser support!)
2. Obviously, the relevant sections of the ECMAScript 5 specification itself, to get an idea for how things are *intended* to work in an ideal world. No, really though; I know that specifications are a scary idea, but the ES (“JavaScript”) specifications are one of the easiest-to-read and most comprehensible specs I've ever seen. They're truly excellent. Of immediate note, and in no particular order,

   - **10.4**, [Establishing an Execution Context](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4): Covers how ‘global code’ and ‘eval code’ are handled, specifically.
   - **10.2**, [Lexical Environments](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2): These describe “where variables are stored.” (The ‘Global Environment’ of interest is one of these.)
   - **10.1**, [Types of Executable Code](http://es5.github.io/#x10.1): Covers what ‘global code’ and ‘Program’s are.
   - **15.1**, [The Global Object](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1): Unfortunately, far less relevant than its title makes it sound. Still worth a skim.

---

<sup>[1]: The discussion in other answers, suggesting that `exports` in Node.js and other CommonJS-compliant systems is somehow related to the *global object*, about which this question asks, is misleading. In terms of system-design, one might be better suited to using their environment's module tools than poking around on the global object … but that's a discussion for another Stack Overflow post. (=</sup>

<sup>[2]: For those of you following along in the spec, it's harder to demonstrate that property-members of the global object are accessible as Identifier dereferences. Start with **10.2.1.2** [Object Environment Records](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.1.2) and **10.2.3** [The Global Environment](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.3) to understand how the global object is linked to an environment, then hop on over to **18.12.3, 18.12.2,** and **18.12.1** in that order, [collectively describing [[Get]] on the global object](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12).</sup>

<sup>***Nota bene***: At no point in this elaboration did I suggest that doing either of these things was a *good idea*. Or, for that matter, that interacting with the *global scope* at all is a good idea. Of no relation to the question at hand, but proffered to soothe my own conscience, I add that I wrap all of my *own* code in a [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) beginning immediately at the top of the file; this, along with religious application of the `var` keyword, ensures that I never interact with JavaScript's handling of the global object *at all*. A huge mess, avoided. You should do that. I said so. I'm smart. (;</sup>

Answer (score 1):

just declare a global object

```
var obj={};
function my_function()
{
 obj['newVariable'] = 'someValue';
}
```

in this way i achieved global variable.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Kba5u/

```
var foo = 'bar';

function changeFooToBaz(){
   foo = 'baz';
}

// changeFooToBaz();
console.log(foo); #=> 'bar'
```

Now, uncomment the call to `changeFooToBaz`:

```
var foo = 'bar';

function changeFooToBaz(){
   foo = 'baz';
}

changeFooToBaz();
console.log(foo); #=> 'baz'
```

`changeFooToBaz` has indeed changed the contents of `foo`, a variable that was declared at a higher scope than the function.